# Last column data overwritten all the column while inserting

Tags: swift3, sqlite

I having this problem when I inserting data row and the result comes out 'SUCCESS'. But when I print out the table, something like below came out. I have been trying on this for days but couldn't figure out where whet wrong.

Logs:

```
Successfully inserted row. >> aaa sss ddd fff
Successfully inserted row. >> zzz xxx ccc vvv
Successfully inserted row. >> 9999999 00000000 aaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbb
Successfully inserted row. >> ccccccccccccc ddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeee fffffffffffffffff
Successfully inserted row. >> gggggggggggg hhhhhhhhhhhh iiiiiiiiiiiii jjjjjjjjjjjjjj
Successfully inserted row. >> kkkkkkkkkkk LLLLLLLLLL mmmmmmmm nnnnnnnnnnnnn
Query Result= id:1 msgID:fff loginID:fff conversationID:fff userID:fff
Query Result= id:2 msgID:vvv loginID:vvv conversationID:vvv userID:vvv
Query Result= id:3 msgID:bbbbbbb loginID:bbbbbbb conversationID:bbbbbbbb userID:bbbbbbbbbbbbb
Query Result= id:4 msgID:ddddddddddd loginID:ddddddddddd conversationID:ddddddddddd userID:fffffffffffffffff
Query Result= id:5 msgID:jjjjjjjjjjjjj loginID:jjjjjjjjjjjj conversationID:jjjjjjjjjjjj userID:jjjjjjjjjjjjjj
Query Result= id:6 msgID:nnnnnnnn loginID:nnnnnnnnnnn conversationID:nnnnnnnnnn userID:nnnnnnnnnnnnn
```

I'm sure the database connection is fine, but it just came out wrong. I even checked if my parameters are input correctly.

When I call my function:

```
DB_Handler.add_msgstatus(loginID: "aaa", conversationID: "sss", msgID: "ddd", userID: "fff")
DB_Handler.add_msgstatus(loginID: "zzz", conversationID: "xxx", msgID: "ccc", userID: "vvv")
DB_Handler.add_msgstatus(loginID: "9999999", conversationID: "00000000", msgID: "aaaaaaa", userID: "bbbbbbbbbbbbb")
DB_Handler.add_msgstatus(loginID: "ccccccccccccc", conversationID: "ddddddddddd", msgID: "eeeeeeeeeeee", userID: "fffffffffffffffff")
DB_Handler.add_msgstatus(loginID: "gggggggggggg", conversationID: "hhhhhhhhhhhh", msgID: "iiiiiiiiiiiii", userID: "jjjjjjjjjjjjjj")
DB_Handler.add_msgstatus(loginID: "kkkkkkkkkkk", conversationID: "LLLLLLLLLL", msgID: "mmmmmmmm", userID: "nnnnnnnnnnnnn")
DB_Handler.getAllMsgStatusInfo()
```

My insert row function:

```
static func add_msgstatus(loginID: String, conversationID: String, msgID: String, userID: String) {

    let queryString = "INSERT INTO msgstatus_tbl (id, msg_id, login_id, conversation_id, user_id) VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
    var preparedStmt: OpaquePointer? = nil
    if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &preparedStmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        sqlite3_bind_text(preparedStmt, 1, msgID, -1, nil)
        sqlite3_bind_text(preparedStmt, 2, loginID, -1, nil)
        sqlite3_bind_text(preparedStmt, 3, conversationID, -1, nil)
        sqlite3_bind_text(preparedStmt, 4, userID, -1, nil)

        if sqlite3_step(preparedStmt) == SQLITE_DONE {
            print("Successfully inserted row. >> \(loginID) \(conversationID) \(msgID) \(userID)")
        } else {
            let errorMessage = String.init(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
            print("Fail to insert row. \(errorMessage)")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(preparedStmt)
    } else {
        let errorMessage = String.init(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
        print("Unable to prepare statement. \(errorMessage)")
    }

}
```

My table:

```
static func create_msgstatus_tbl() {

    let queryString = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS msgstatus_tbl (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, msg_id VARCHAR(255), login_id VARCHAR(255), conversation_id VARCHAR(255), user_id VARCHAR(255));"
    var preparedStmt: OpaquePointer? = nil
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryString, -1, &preparedStmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        if sqlite3_step(preparedStmt) == SQLITE_DONE {
            print("Table (msgstatus_tbl) exists/ created.")
        } else {
            print("Table (msgstatus_tbl) could not be created.")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(preparedStmt)
    } else {
        let errorMessage = String.init(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
        print("Unable to prepare statement. \(errorMessage)")
    }

}
```

My retrieve data function:

```
static func getAllMsgStatusInfo() {

    let queryString = "SELECT * FROM msgstatus_tbl;"
    var preparedStmt: OpaquePointer? = nil
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryString, -1, &preparedStmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        var msgID = ""
        var loginID = ""
        var conversationID = ""
        var userID = ""
        var id = ""
        while (sqlite3_step(preparedStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            id = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(preparedStmt, 0))
            msgID = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(preparedStmt, 1))
            loginID = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(preparedStmt, 2))
            conversationID = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(preparedStmt, 3))
            userID = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(preparedStmt, 4))
            print("Query Result= id:\(id) msgID:\(msgID) loginID:\(loginID) conversationID:\(conversationID) userID:\(userID)")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(preparedStmt)
    } else {
        let errorMessage = String.init(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
        print("Unable to prepare statement. \(errorMessage)")
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with swift, but it seems odd to me that you a) have a primary key *without* autoincrement, and b) assigns a `null` in your insert statement. Try having `id` as an autoincrement and do not assign it anything in your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: The 'id' is working fine currently, but I tried your suggestion anyway to see if that caused my problem. Unfortunately, I still having the data inserted wrongly.

Comment: Sorry if that was unhelpful. Have you tried a numbered parameter, i.e. `?1, ?2, ?3, ?4`. I am just as baffled as you are.

Comment: I tried all sort of data vary from number, alphanumberic or just characters, it just insert the last column data as all column data.. It really just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Could it be that you are not *retrieving* the columns properly? If possible, go in through the back, i.e. open the SQLite database in the command line shell (https://sqlite.org/cli.html) or some other SQLite viewer. And show us your code for how you are retrieving the query.

Comment: I added my retrieve data function and yeah, I did view the database using external viewer. The result is the same, all the column in a row are filled with the last column data of that row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do one thing.
When you use `sqlite3_bind_text(preparedStmt, 1, msgID, -1, nil)` then just follow these following steps -:

1. `let msgId = msgID as NSString`
2. `sqlite3_bind_text(preparedStmt, 1, msgId.utf8String, -1, nil)`

Do these same things for all your next `sqlite3_bind_text` statement as mentioned in your code.

I also faced same problem like you. And it is working now for me. I hope it will work for you.